# Using WeakReference Safely

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

Say I have a class `Publisher`  with a list of `Subscriber` objects stored in a list of `WeakReference<>`

```
public interface Subscriber {
    void update();
}

public class Publisher {
    private final List<WeakReference<Subscriber>> subscribers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public void subscribe(final Subscriber subscriber) { 
        subscribers.add(new WeakReference<>(subscriber)); 
    }

    public void publish() { ...
```

Between a call to `Publisher::subscribe` and a later call to `Publisher::publish`, a `Subscriber` in the weak reference list could have been garbage collected, so I need to check if it is `null` before using it.

My question is whether or not the code bellow would be safe a safe implementation for `publish`?

```
public void publish() { 
    //filter out garbage collected items
    subscribers = subscribers.stream()
            .filter(sub -> sub.get() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //use the remaing objects
    for (final WeakReference<Subscriber> sub : subscribers) {
        sub.get().update());
    }
}
```

Is it possible that between filtering `subscribers` and the calls to `Subscriber::update` that the garbage collector has destroyed another object?
Should I be doing a second `null` check when updating?

```
    for (final WeakReference<Subscriber> sub : subscribers) {
        if (sub.get() != null) {
            sub.get().update());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suggested second nullity check isn't good enough either, as the first call to `get()` could return a non-null value, and the second call could return `null`. I'd suggest:

```
for (WeakReference<Subscriber> subRef : subscribers) {
    Subscriber sub = subRef.get();
    if (sub != null) {
        sub.update();
    }
}
```

Or using Java 8's streams (untested):

```
subscribers
    .stream()
    .map(WeakReference::get)
    .filter(s -> s != null)
    .forEach(Subscriber::update);
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, the GC could perform a cleanup during any line of the execution?

Comment: @flkes: Yes, if nothing else is keeping it alive.

Comment: GC cannot destroy the object as soon after `get()` and while the strong reference that is returned by `get()` is in scope.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, but the point is that in the OP's code they're calling `get()` and checking whether or not the result is null, but then calling `get()` again later - and there's no guarantee it will still be non-null at that point.

Comment: Yes, this `if (sub.get() != null) {
            sub.get().update());
        }` pattern is no good.